# algorithm for drawing a sort of nozzle(line),whose is direction determined by the mouse?

Tags: c++

i am using The old Turbo C++ and am a beginner.
This is the code of a ongoing project that i am planning.

the circle moves withe WSAD keys
But the problem is that i want the nozzle(a line from the center) of that circle to follow the movement of the mouse,but i cant figure out the mathematical part to restrict the length of that nozzle to, say 30 pixels. the line goes on touching the pointer's location.

I tried to use the Distance formula and the line equation to get with an expression which has both the slope and the length of the line. But the problem here is that there is an square root in the denominator, and i think that is causing the problem

Most of the code here is unnecessary for the following problem, so please ignore

here is the relevant code

```
   originx=getmaxx()/2;
   originy=getmaxy()/2;

   while(doga==0)      //main game loop
     {      if(kbhit())
    op=getch();
        if(limiter>10)             //limiter is used to restrict the motion of the  circle for a limited                                 //  time
   { op=0;limiter=0;}         // otherwise the cirlce moves in that direction unless another                                      //key is pressed


       //movement of the circle
    if(op==72)
      { originy--;  limiter++;}
    if(op==80)
          {originy++;  limiter++;}
    if(op==75)
     { originx--;  limiter++ ;}
    if(op==77)
     { originx++;  limiter++;    }

    circle(originx,originy,5);

      mouseposi(x,y,cl);
   printf(" %d  %d",x,y);
   printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");

     m=sloper(originx,originy,x,y);

     line(originx,originy,80/sqrt(1+m*m),m*80/sqrt(1+m*m)); //THIS LINE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS


      delay(30);
      cleardevice();
      if(op==49)          //for exiting
        doga=2;
    }


   }
```

Comment: READ THE 5th line from the bottom

Comment: If most of the code is irrelevant for the question it might be helpful to get rid of it and highlight the pertinent parts instead of making us scroll through and look for that comment about the one important line

Comment: The name of your function isn't `line` it's `draw_line`. Is this your error, or are you calling code from somewhere else?

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: you want to draw the radius of a circle, and it must be aligned with `(circle center, mouse position)` ? Is that it ?

Comment: @ereOn no , the  circle's radius is fixed, that is 5 pixels, i wish to draw a line from the centre of a particular length , that follows the mouse regardless the distance of the mouse from the circle

Comment: @nbrooks as i said , most of the code is irrelevant , i have edited the code on your advice.. draw_line is used to convert the entered coordinates into cartesian form, i.e. (0,0) will be at the centre of the screen, not at the top left corner

Comment: I fail to see the difference with what I wrote. Also, I never said the radius wasn't fixed. You should include a drawing in your question to make your intent clearer.

Comment: @ereOn yes you are right , understood your question in a wrong way, i want to do the same thing that you said , instead the radius of the circle should be protruding a bit out of the circle

Comment: Sounds to me that a simple `length * cos(angle)`/`length * sin(angle)` would give the coordinates. And as the length is only 5 pixels long and thus precision is not paramount, you could even make that faster using a cosinus table.

Comment: @ereOn Could you please post it as an answer, with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `(x,y)` be the point you're after, `(ox, oy)` be your origin, and `(mx, my)` be the mouse location.

The vector from the origin to the mouse is `(dx, dy) = (mx - ox, my - oy)`.

The distance between the mouse and the origin is the same as the norm of that vector:

```
distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

Normalizing (scaling) the vector to get a new vector of length 1 ("unit length") we get

```
nx = dx / distance;
ny = dy / distance;
```

And finally we can scale those coordinates by the desired length (remembering to add back the origin)

```
x = ox + length * nx;
y = oy + length * ny;
```

Comment: I'd rename `norm` as `distance` (as that's what it is) and state that normalising means 'making the distance equal to one unit whilst keeping the direction the same'

Comment: @Skizz: I rearranged a bit. Better?